# Find the service creation date in Windows?

Tags: forensics

If on a compromised system you are trying to analyze newly installed services or when services were installed, how do you do that. Where can I find the creation date for a certain service in the Windows registry?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is no way to determine the creation date for a particular Windows service as both the services applet and the Windows registry does not store any dates relating to creations.

There is, however, a last modified date which is hidden away from view (including in the Windows registry editor) but can be accessed using [RegQueryInfoKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724902%28VS.85%29.aspx). Since all Windows services stored in the registry, you can check the Last Modified Date against the registry keys related to the service in question by looking in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services`

Alternatively, if you export the registry key(s) you want information on as a text file, the last modified date for each key is written in the text file.

[image]

Finally, a [solution using PowerShell to return the Last Modified Date has already been discussed on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6537346/2632171).

Comment: Alas this ain't working for me. I get No Last Write Time when exporting Services

Answer (score 10):

Starting in Vista, service creation is logged to the "System" event log under Service Control Manager event ID 7045.

For example, the following command:

```
C:\>sc create hello binpath= notepad.exe
[SC] CreateService SUCCESS
```

Produced the following event log entry:

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Service Control Manager
Date:          12/16/2014 3:00:00 PM
Event ID:      7045
Task Category: None
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Classic
User:          DOMAIN\username
Computer:      WORKSTATION.DOMAIN.local
Description:
A service was installed in the system.

Service Name:  hello
Service File Name:  notepad.exe
Service Type:  user mode service
Service Start Type:  demand start
Service Account:  LocalSystem
```

Comment: Is there any way to access the event log entry from the registry?

Comment: No, they are separate things.